# Set Id of HTML Div element dynamically inside ASP.NET MVC Razor view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

In my MVC razor view i am trying to set the Id of a Div element dynamically inside the for loop.

```
@for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
<div class="landing-inc" id="section_@i"></div>
}
```

The Id if Div should be section_0 , section_1 etc based on the i value.

The above code works fine in browser but i am converting this razor view to a pdf file and there its causing an issue.

I am just looking if there is another way or syntax to set the Id of div dynamically

Comment: What error or issue are you having?  The code you wrote is the proper way to set a dynamic id.

Comment: Th PDF is getting corrupted, the DF dowsn't load.. when i remove this part of code its working

Comment: can you share your code of where the conversion happens from view to PDF?